# How to align to center md-hint in Angular Material 2?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2

My snippet.

```
<md-hint>About</md-hint>
<p data-text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

View

[image]

[image]

How to make the md-hint align to center? been stuck for a while..

---

**Update**

I did the css way. This is what I am avoiding to do.. If you know the angular material2 way to solve this please help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this :

```
<div [style.text-align]="'center'"><md-hint>About</md-hint></div>
```

Comment: And by giving it a class  ?

Comment: Oh wait, I thought you were using it with an input. Let me edit my post.

Comment: Here you go, try this instead !

Comment: Less is more ! Glad I could help, remember to mark the question as resolved !

Comment: sure __________

Answer (score 1):

If it's fine with you to set a fixed width to the `<p>` tag, then this should work:

**CSS:**

```
.my-class{
  display:flex;
  width:300px;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;      
}
::ng-deep .mat-hint{
  width:100% !important;
  text-align:center !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="my-class">
    <p data-text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <md-hint>About</md-hint>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/sDzlXTuXYtcFUgQJnbDO?p=preview)**

As `ng-deep` will might be deprecated soon, you can consider to add encapsulation.None to the component decorator and remove ::ng-deep. But for now it works.